# JSON parsing with Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

```
bfunc({   
"query": {   
  "count": 1,   
  "created": "2013-05-03T06:20:01Z",   
  "lang": "en-US",   
  "diagnostics": {   
  "publiclyCallable": "true",   
  "cache": {    
    "execution-start-time": "32",   
    "execution-stop-time": "32",   
    "execution-time": "0",   
    "method": "GET",   
    "type": "MEMCACHED",   
    "content": "http://www.vtualerts.com/robots.txt"   
   });
```

This is my JSON data which I need to parse using javascript and jQuery. I tried to do it like this......

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>   
<script>   
$.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {    
    var output= data.cbfunc.query.count+ "" + data.cbfunc.query.created;     
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;    
});
```

but I am getting an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/shivratna/Desktop/myjson.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Please help.

Sincere thanks

Comment: try placing alert("data :"+JSON.stringify(data)); Maybe you are getting data. verify by placing this line.

Comment: `bfunc(...)` is not valid JSON. It's not even valid JSONP.

Comment: It's not even valid JSONP. You lack closing brackets.

Comment: use alert() for test but seems you have 4 "{" but only 1 "}"

Comment: @EmRa228 `console.log()` is better

Comment: your json is invalid ,check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid JSON. Read at [json.org](http://www.json.org/) for the proper structure for JSON. What you have there is JSONP. Before anything else, check your JSON, as they don't close properly. You lack closing braces.

To turn it into valid JSON, remove the padding function like so:

```
{   
  "query": {   
    "count": 1,   
    "created": "2013-05-03T06:20:01Z",   
    "lang": "en-US",   
    "diagnostics": {   
      "publiclyCallable": "true",   
      "cache": {    
        "execution-start-time": "32",   
        "execution-stop-time": "32",   
        "execution-time": "0",   
        "method": "GET",   
        "type": "MEMCACHED",   
        "content": "http://www.vtualerts.com/robots.txt"   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `1` and `"1"` are valid JSON as well. Even `null` is valid JSON

Comment: @JanDvorak well in his case, it should start with `{}` but anyways, I'll rephrase.

Answer (score -1):

Why you are using json data like that,this is invalid ,you can use json data like

```
{ "query": {
"count": 1,
"created": "2013-05-03T06:20:01Z",
"lang": "en-US",
"diagnostics": {
    "publiclyCallable": "true",
    "cache": {
        "execution-start-time": "32",
        "execution-stop-time": "32",
        "execution-time": "0",
        "method": "GET",
        "type": "MEMCACHED",
        "content": "http://www.vtualerts.com/robots.txt"
    }
}
}
}
```

Your final code..

```
    $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {    
      var output= data.query.count+ "" + data.query.created;     
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;    
   });
```

Comment: Are you sure about this?

Comment: Thnax everyone for you help. Actually i am getting this json data from YQL console. I am not writing it on my own.